# facebook: Value of the zip and address of current_location

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Why can not I get the value of the zip and address of the user? All permissions are set correctly.

Example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "current_location": {
        "city": "Capivari de Baixo",
        "state": "Santa Catarina",
        "country": "Brazil",
        "zip": "",
        "id": 110688912336502,
        "name": "Capivari de Baixo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The value of the zip code is always empty
"zip": "",

And is there any way to get the user's address?

Comment: according to the link from @Martey, there is still no resolution. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address field (which included the ZIP code) [was introduced by Facebook in January 2011](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446/) and disabled [four days later](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/). At the time, they wrote:

> We look forward to re-enabling this improved feature in the next few weeks.

Almost a year later, the feature has still not been re-enabled.